# MultiScreen Support layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am new in Android and i'm very much Confused for screen size and density .
i am using minimumSdkVersion 15 and CompiledSdkversion 23.i have read DeveloperSite docs.but still confused,kindly give me some working example or links for it which would help me understand and save my Time.i'm also confused in writing portrait and Landscape mode Xml file.Please help me out

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Use the linear layout concept...it will better to show in all resolution of the devices

Answer (score 1):

First read this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Google's Android Developers Guide is great place to start. Read them patiently, check also `Training` to write some code.

As you're beginner try also this Udacity course: [Android development for beginners](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837)

I highly recommend you if you want to know Android `views`, `layouts` and of course its `attributes`. Don't worry it would explain you everything by example and writing code.

Also give a try this great Youtube course by Slidenerd: [Android Tutorial for Beginners [HD 1080p]](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa)

Slidenerd starts with explaining app lifecircle, which would help you to understand how a view is changing form portrait to landscape and vice versa, than he teaches various of layouts like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `TableLayout`.

I recommend you these things, because I've already watched them and much more, but these would be enough for your start in Android Development

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different layout (.xml files) for different screens.
Refer this link for better understanding.
[link here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html)

Comment: sir i think layout-small,layout-large are deprecated now .plz give some layout-<sw360>,layout-sw<620> folder example to supports multiple screen